# React-Admin styling issue with SingleFieldList and ChipField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yarnpkg, react-admin

I am working on React project based on React Admin 4.12.1.
It worked fine before I update the packages by running `yarn upgrade`.
The issue is that, I cannot see the text inside ChipField anymore.

```
<SingleFieldList link={false}>
    <ChipField source="name" />
 </SingleFieldList>
```

And I could see that, the SingleFieldList color style is overriding the ChipField's color attribute.(as you can in the screenshots). And I think this comes from Mui package update.
How I avoid this style overriding to make the text visible?

Changed Package List:

```
"@babel/preset-react": 7.18.6 -> 7.22.15,
"@date-io/moment": 2.16.1 -> 2.17.0,
"@emotion/react": 11.11.0 -> 11.11.0,
"@emotion/styled": 11.10.6 -> 11.11.0,
"@mui/icons-material": 5.11.16 -> 5.14.16,
"@mui/material": 5.11.16 -> 5.14.16,
"@mui/styles": 5.12.0 -> 5.14.16,
"@mui/x-date-pickers": 5.0.0-beta.0 -> 5.0.20,
"@react-pdf/renderer": 3.1.9 -> 3.1.14,
"jsona": 1.11.0 -> 1.12.1,
"ra-data-json-server": 4.8.4 -> 4.15.2,
"react-select": 5.7.3 -> 5.7.7,
"webpack-dev-server": 4.15.0 -> 4.15.1

"devDependencies": {
  "@testing-library/dom": 9.0.1 -> 9.3.3,
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": 5.16.5 -> 5.17.0,
  "@webpack-cli/serve": 2.0.4 -> 2.0.5
},
```

[How I see the chip now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVXTy.png)
[Overriding style after yarn upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luUNV.png)

I tried to override the React Admin theme but did not success.
There are many codes using that SingleFieldList and ChipField so would be great to have a simple-change solution.
Thanks

Comment: [React Admin v4.16.0](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/releases/tag/v4.16.0) introduced a change in the way `SingleFieldList` renders child `ChipField`, with a minor (yet desired) [BC break](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/9439). Could it be the cause of the issue you are facing?